# How does grouping work in Javascript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this Javascript:

```
String.method('deentityify', function () {
    // The entity table.  It maps entity names to
    // characters.
    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };

    // Return the deentityify method
    return function () {

        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());

document.writeln('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify());
```

What goes into the last function as a and b, and why?

I get that we're splitting up the string I'm passing in into 3 groups, but I don't understand why `&lt;` is going into a and why just `lt` is going into b.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument contains the whole match, all consecutive arguments are the matched groups. The last two arguments are the offset and full input string.

```
var input = '&lt;&quot;&gt;'
input.replace( /&([^&;]+);/g, function (a, b)
```

The pattern matches all occurrences of `&` + every `non-&` + `;`.

```
a      b
&lt;   lt 
&quot; quot
&gt;   gt
```

See also: [MDN: `String.replace` with a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: So, the first match is &lt; right?  Where does the lt come from?  Sorry - I know I'm being dense.

Comment: `lt` are all `non-&` characters between the `&` and the `;`. It is captured by the parens.

Comment: Argh.  I'm still not getting it.  I don't understand why we're passing two things per match.  It seems to me that we're only matching 3 things: &lt; &quot; &gt;  Are we really capturing 6 things?

Comment: @TerryDonaghe The parens **create** a new group. `a` contains the full match and `b` the first group. The pattern is found three time, and since you've added the `g` (global) flag to the RegEx, the function is called **three** times, with `a` and `b` as specified in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rob W!  I think I've finally got it.  I looked at the doc link you provided and that helps.  My brain hurts.